# Data Mismatch after Left Join SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one that contains production data and the other has forecasted data. I am joining the two tables to compare the actual production data to forecasted data. 
My sample tables are as follows:

```
**Prod Tbl**                
Product Plant   pmonth    pyear  quantity
B007    2       January   2014   45
B007    2       February  2014   270
B007    2       March     2014   270
B007    2       April     2014   45
B007    2       May       2014   90
B007    2       May       2014   90
B007    2       June      2014   90
B007    2       June      2014   90
B007    2       July      2014   135
B007    2       July      2014   45
B007    2       August    2014   135
B007    2       August    2014   135
B007    2       July      2015   90
B007    2       August    2014  135
B007    2       September 2014  135
B007    2       September 2015  135
B007    2       October   2015  90
B007    2       September 2014  135
B007    2       September 2014  90
B007    2       September 2014  90
B007    2       November  2014  254
B007    2       May       2016  90
B007    2       August    2016  135
B007    2       October   2016  87

**Forecast Tbl**                
Product Plant   Fmonth   Fyear  Fqty
B007    2       July      2017  100
B007    2       August    2017  100
B007    2       September 2017  100
B007    2       October   2017  100
B007    2      Novenmber  2017  100
B007    2      December   2017  100
```

**Query Used to Join:**

```
Select a.Product,
       a.plant,
       b.pmonth,
       b.pyear,
       coalesce(b.quantity,0) as quantity,
       a.fmonth,
       a.fyear,coalesce(a.fqty,0) as fqty 
from   
Frcast_Tbl as a 
  left join on Prod_Tbl as b on (a.Product = b.Product 
                             and a.Plant = b.plant
                             and b.pMonth = a.fMonth);
```

**Result:
After Joining**

```
Product Plant   Pmonth    Pyear Quantity    Fmonth    Fyear fqty
B007    2       July      2014  180         July      2017  100
B007    2       July      2015  90          July      2017  100
B007    2       August    2014  405         August    2017  100
B007    2       August    2016  315         August    2017  100
B007    2       September 2014  450         September 2017  100
B007    2       September 2015  135         September 2017  100
B007    2       October   2016  177         October   2017  100
B007    2       October   2015  90          October   2017  100
B007    2       November  2014  356         November  2017  100
B007    2       December  2016  90          December  2017  100
B007    2       January   2015  90          January   2018  100
B007    2       January   2016  90          January   2018  100
B007    2       January   2014  45          January   2018  100
B007    2       January   2017  90          January   2018  100
B007    2       February  2014  270         February  2018  99
B007    2       March     2014  270         March     2018  101
B007    2       March     2017  90          March     2018  101
B007    2       April     2014  45          April     2018  100
B007    2       May       2016  90          May       2018  100
B007    2       May       2014  180         May       2018  100
B007    2       May       2017  90          May       2018  100
```

**Filtered for a particular year to better explain the problem**

```
Producr plant   pmonth  pyear   quantity    fmonth  fyear   fqty
B007    2       August   2016   315         August   2017   100
B007    2       October  2016   177         October  2017   100
B007    2       December 2016   90          December 2017   100
```

**Desired Table**

```
Product Plant   Pmonth  Pyear   Quantity    fmonth     fyear    fqty
B007    2       January  2016   90          null       null     0
B007    2       May      2016   90          null       null     0
B007    2       June     2016   270         null       null     0
B007    2       null     null   0           July       2017    100
B007    2       August   2016   315         August     2017    100
B007    2       null     null   0           September  2017    100
B007    2       October  2016   177         October    2017    100
B007    2       null     null   0           November   2017    100
B007    2       December 2016   90          December   2017    100
```

What my query is doing is that it joins item, plant and month using left join but I want my resultant table to display all the months for both prod and frcast  and in cases where month is not found, display null or zeros. Please help.

Comment: use FULL Join instead of LEFT join

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Seem like Mysql

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. People here are suggesting FULL OUTER JOIN, which e.g. MySQL doesn't support (afaik.)

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this.  The Subquery after FULL JOIN is to extract only one year from Products table.
I added a CASE for ORDER BY too.

**One year version**

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.Product,b.Product) AS PRODUCT,
       COALESCE(a.plant,b.plant) AS PLANT,
       b.pmonth,
       b.pyear,
       coalesce(b.quantity,0) as quantity,
       a.fmonth AS FMONTH, 
       a.fyear,
       coalesce(a.fqty,0) as fqty 
FROM FORECAST A
FULL JOIN (SELECT * FROM PROD WHERE pyear=2016) B on a.Product = b.Product 
                                                        and a.Plant = b.plant
                                                        and A.fmonth = b.pMonth
ORDER  BY CASE COALESCE(b.pmonth, a.fmonth)
            WHEN 'January' THEN 1
            WHEN 'February' THEN 2
            WHEN 'March' THEN 3
            WHEN 'April' THEN 4
            WHEN 'May' THEN 5
            WHEN 'June' THEN 6
            WHEN 'July' THEN 7
            WHEN 'August' THEN 8
            WHEN 'September' THEN 9
            WHEN 'October' THEN 10
            WHEN 'November' THEN 11
            WHEN 'December' THEN 12
          END ;
```

Pls note that your sample data (first table) are not complete.

Output:

```
+-------------+-------+---------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+
|     PRODUCT | PLANT | pmonth  | pyear | quantity |  FMONTH   | fyear | fqty |
+-------------+-------+---------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+
|     B007    |     2 | January | 2016  |       90 | NULL      | NULL  |    0 |
|     B007    |     2 | May     | 2016  |       90 | NULL      | NULL  |    0 |
|     B007    |     2 | June    | 2016  |      270 | NULL      | NULL  |    0 |
|     B007    |     2 | NULL    | NULL  |        0 | July      | 2017  |  100 |
|     B007    |     2 | August  | 2016  |      135 | August    | 2017  |  100 |
|     B007    |     2 | NULL    | NULL  |        0 | September | 2017  |  100 |
|     B007    |     2 | October | 2016  |       87 | October   | 2017  |  100 |
|     B007    |     2 | NULL    | NULL  |        0 | November  | 2017  |  100 |
|     B007    |     2 | NULL    | NULL  |        0 | December  | 2017  |  100 |
+-------------+-------+---------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+
```

**Added: multi year version, with group by on PROD table**

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.Product,b.Product) AS PRODUCT,
       COALESCE(a.plant,b.plant) AS PLANT,
       b.pmonth,
       COALESCE(b.pyear,Y.pyear) AS pyear,
       COALESCE(b.quantity,0) as quantity,
       a.fmonth AS FMONTH, 
       a.fyear,
       coalesce(a.fqty,0) as fqty 
FROM FORECAST A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT pyear FROM PROD /* WHERE pyear IN (2015,2016)*/ ) Y
FULL JOIN (SELECT Product, Plant, pyear, pmonth, SUM(quantity) AS quantity 
            FROM PROD /*WHERE pyear IN (2015,2016)*/ 
            GROUP BY Product, Plant, pyear, pmonth
            ) B on a.Product = b.Product 
                    and a.Plant = b.plant
                    and A.fmonth = b.pMonth
                    AND Y.pyear= B.pyear
ORDER  BY COALESCE(b.pyear,Y.pyear), CASE COALESCE(b.pmonth, a.fmonth)
            WHEN 'January' THEN 1
            WHEN 'February' THEN 2
            WHEN 'March' THEN 3
            WHEN 'April' THEN 4
            WHEN 'May' THEN 5
            WHEN 'June' THEN 6
            WHEN 'July' THEN 7
            WHEN 'August' THEN 8
            WHEN 'September' THEN 9
            WHEN 'October' THEN 10
            WHEN 'November' THEN 11
            WHEN 'December' THEN 12
          END ;
```

Output:

```
+---------+-------+-----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+
| PRODUCT | PLANT |  pmonth   | pyear | quantity |  FMONTH   | fyear | fqty |
+---------+-------+-----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+
| B007    |     2 | January   |  2014 |       45 | NULL      | NULL  |    0 |
| B007    |     2 | February  |  2014 |      270 | NULL      | NULL  |    0 |
| B007    |     2 | March     |  2014 |      270 | NULL      | NULL  |    0 |
| B007    |     2 | April     |  2014 |       45 | NULL      | NULL  |    0 |
| B007    |     2 | May       |  2014 |      180 | NULL      | NULL  |    0 |
| B007    |     2 | June      |  2014 |      180 | NULL      | NULL  |    0 |
| B007    |     2 | July      |  2014 |      180 | July      | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | August    |  2014 |      405 | August    | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | September |  2014 |      450 | September | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | NULL      |  2014 |        0 | October   | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | November  |  2014 |      254 | November  | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | NULL      |  2014 |        0 | December  | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | July      |  2015 |       90 | July      | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | NULL      |  2015 |        0 | August    | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | September |  2015 |      135 | September | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | October   |  2015 |       90 | October   | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | NULL      |  2015 |        0 | November  | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | NULL      |  2015 |        0 | December  | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | January   |  2016 |       90 | NULL      | NULL  |    0 |
| B007    |     2 | May       |  2016 |       90 | NULL      | NULL  |    0 |
| B007    |     2 | June      |  2016 |      270 | NULL      | NULL  |    0 |
| B007    |     2 | NULL      |  2016 |        0 | July      | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | August    |  2016 |      135 | August    | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | NULL      |  2016 |        0 | September | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | October   |  2016 |       87 | October   | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | NULL      |  2016 |        0 | November  | 2017  |  100 |
| B007    |     2 | NULL      |  2016 |        0 | December  | 2017  |  100 |
+---------+-------+-----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+
```

Comment: The above query does not work because my forecast table will only contain forward looking data and hence will not contain any previous years unlike my prod table.

Comment: Your updated query works perfectly for 2016. Thank you! but if I were to compare for 2014 and 2017 I would run into trouble. My data looks back three years and looks forward till whenever available and in this case 2018.

Comment: I already was working on it.  But I need to know: on PROD table can you have more rows for same year / month?

Comment: @Sqlnewbee   added new version multi year

Comment: The prod table is retrieved from actual production data. I do not see how I can have more rows for same year/month. I may have not fully understood what you are asking for, please clarify.

Comment: check your sample data for 2014 above

Comment: anyway I put group by to solve it.  If you are sure there are not "duplicates", you can remove GROUP BY and SUM in my second query.

Comment: Thank you! I will run it and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your  help! I ran the query and validated the data and it looks perfect.

Comment: @Sqlnewbee if my answer was usefult, you should remember to upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Use FULL OUTER JOIN when you are filtering records for specific year

```
Select a.Product,a.plant,b.pmonth,b.pyear,coalesce(b.quantity,0) as quantity,a.fmonth,a.fyear,coalesce(a.fqty,0) as fqty 
from Frcast_Tbl as a 
FULL OUTER JOIN on Prod_Tbl as b on a.Product = b.Product and 
                                    a.Plant = b.plant and 
                                    b.pMonth = a.fMonth
```

Comment: I edited the query as full outer join but it yields the same result as left join. Is there any way I can create a cross join where every fyear maps with every pyear , every fmonth maps with every pmonth and then perform a left join.